# Memcache return true after set, but item doesn't save

Tags: php, memcached

Use Memcache php class to interact with the memcached. At the beginning all works fine, but after hours of work, items doesn't save in memcached. Server has enough free memory and lifetime of item is correct. What's happened?

For example:

```
$storage->set($key, $value, false, $lifetime); //return true
```

But when i check it, memcached return NULL;

```
$storage->get($key); //return null
```

Comment: You say 'lifetime is correct' but are you sure - you may have set it to `time()+$amount`, which won't work after $amount of time has elapsed.

Comment: No worries - it happens to us all :) I've submitted this as an answer in case someone else gets the same issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say 'lifetime is correct' but are you sure - you may have set it to `time()+$amount`, which won't work after `$amount` of time has elapsed.